# Modulo calculation does not execute

Tags: c#

```
public static string ToHex(this decimal num)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (num != 0)
        {
            if ((num % 16) < 10)
                sb.Append((num % 16).ToString());

            else if (num % 16 == 10)
                sb.Append("A");

            else if (num % 16 == 11)
                sb.Append("B");

            else if (num % 16 == 12)
                sb.Append("C");

            else if (num % 16 == 13)
                sb.Append("D");

            else if (num % 16 == 14)
                sb.Append("E");

            else if (num % 16 == 15)
                sb.Append("F");

            num = ((num / 16) - ((num / 16) % 1));
        }
        return sb.ToString().Reverse();
    }
```

So at the line num = ((num / 16) - ((num / 16) % 1)); for some reason ((num / 16) % 1) does not execute.

I inserted 1354153 to num and after the calculation num is 84634.5625 (I checked it on debugger mode) when ((num / 16) % 1) should have "removed" the fraction.

Why doesn't it execute and if it does why does the result comes out wrong?

I'm a beginner so sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: If this is not an exercise, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) out for formatting numbers as hexadecimal strings. If it is, then I think you may be running into problems because `decimal` may not be a whole number.

Comment: I would also suggest debugging the code to see exactly what goes wrong there.

Comment: I'd be curious whether *(num / 16m) % 1m* would make any difference. In any case, it seems like you really want *[Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(num / 16)*

Comment: I've run your code and after the line in question I'm getting 84634.0000 as num, so are you sure you don't have a typo in your actual code somewhere?

Comment: The line `num = ((num / 16) - ((num / 16) % 1));` seem to be working fine for 1354153 . Note that your `num %16` produces non-integer result and hence value when converted to string is likely different from what you expect.

Comment: Note - code as posted does not compile. There is a good chance that OP fixed part of the code and instead of fixing compile time errors tried to "run anyway - yes".

Comment: And of course if this isn't an exercise and you are just trying to display hex then `((int)1354153m).ToString("X")` would be the easiest.  Now since you aren't provisioning for base-16 decimal places, then the int cast wouldn't lose any provision.  If you do need fractional hex, you need to add a decimal point in there somewhere.

Comment: I would use instead `num = num << 4` or `num = (num - num % 16) / 16` in order to calculate the next number. Decimals are giving you a hard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why the modulus doesn't work, but wouldn't using `Math.Floor` instead be an easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: Haha, don't worry about it, happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I get different results than you. However, there is a problem in this line:

```
sb.Append((num % 16).ToString());
```

Because `num` is `decimal`, you might get different result depending on your culture, but it will probably return something like `9.000`. Which, when you add it to a string, causes problems.

Your code will also not work if you actually put in a number which is not an integer.

Also, your last line should be something like:

```
return new string(sb.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
```

Otherwise it doesn't compile.

All this leads me to believe that you have not actually debugged or even tested this version of the code. If this is an exercise, I would suggest trying this with an `int` instead of decimal. If not, please use the [standard format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
((int)1354153m).ToString("X")
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it literally 10 seconds before you posted your comment. Thanks!
Oh, and my last line is fine, the method works perfectly. Is there a problem that I am unaware?

Comment: Well, your last line doesn't compile for me (VS 2012), so yes there seems to be a problem...